# elixir poison not able to decode JSON

Tags: json, elixir, decode, elixir-poison

I am trying below code

```
data = Poison.decode!(payload)
    |> ProperCase.to_snake_case
Logger.info("data is #{data}")
```

Where the payload is from Messging Queue

```
    {
      "name":"Joe",
      "id": "13",
      "version": 0
    }
```

With this I am getting an error

```
[error] Could not process PerfectFlight: %Protocol.UndefinedError{description: "", protocol: String.Chars, value: %{"id" => "13", "name" => "Joe", "version" => 0}}
```

However, If I change my input json to

```
 "{
  \"name\":\"Joe\",
  \"id\": \"13\",
  \"version\": 0
}"
```

The `Poison.decode()` works pefectly fine. Now the issue is that I don't want to change my input `JSON` because of many reasons. What am I missing?

**Edit** : The code was failing not at the decode but on the next line `Logger.info("data is #{data}")`. Since the output of `decode` function is not a `String` I should rather use IO.inspect as below. Accepting Adams answer for his confidence in decode function.

```
data = Poison.decode!(payload)
    |> ProperCase.to_snake_case
IO.inspect(data)
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ start a pipeline with the term: `payload |> Poison.decode!() |> ProperCase.to_snake_case()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with Poison:

```
iex(1)> Poison.decode!(~S'{"name":"Joe", "id": "13", "version": 0}')
%{"id" => "13", "name" => "Joe", "version" => 0}
```

Your example also works for me:

```
iex(1)> payload = ~S'{"name":"Joe", "id": "13", "version": 0}'
"{\"name\":\"Joe\", \"id\": \"13\", \"version\": 0}"
iex(2)> Poison.decode!(payload) |> ProperCase.to_snake_case
%{"id" => "13", "name" => "Joe", "version" => 0}
```

The error you are getting is probably because something somewhere is trying to convert a map to a string:

```
iex(1)> IO.puts %{"id" => "13", "name" => "Joe", "version" => 0}
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol String.Chars not implemented for %{"id" => "13", "name" => "Joe", "version" => 0}
```

It looks like you're getting an error while trying to debug your problem. You could use `IO.inspect` instead of `IO.puts` for debugging, and see if you can get a more helpful error message.

Comment: The difference in those additional single quotes. Here is what I was trying `Poison.decode!({"name":"Joe", "id": "13", "version": 0})`. This is how the message comes as a `payload` from `Messaging Queue`.

Comment: @veer7 that's not possible, because JSON is not valid elixir syntax. You would have got  `SyntaxError`, not a `Protocol.UndefinedError`.

Comment: I'm getting you quoted the JSON, then got the error trying to log the successfully parsed resulting map with `IO.puts`.

Comment: Correct! It's a syntax error with `Poison.decode!({"name":"Joe", "id": "13", "version": 0})`.